# Understanding the output of margins() in R?

Tags: r, interaction, interpretation

I want to do some basic OLS regression analysis but I am confused about the output given by the `margins()` function from the [`margins` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=margins). If I calculate the results by hand, I get completely  different results and now I don't know what result to trust.

Here is an example code:

```r
tab <- lm(populism_avg_std ~ eligibility_dummy * 
    core_globalizationwinners + male + east_europe, 
    data = tomodel_pid_full_pop)
margins <- lm(populism_avg_std ~ eligibility_dummy * 
    core_globalizationwinners + male + east_europe, 
    data = tomodel_pid_full_pop) %>%
  margins(at = list(core_globalizationwinners = c("0", "1"))) %>%
  summary() %>%
  filter(factor == "eligibility_dummy")
```

In the regression I get the following (relevant) coefficients:

```r
eligibility_dummy = -0.24
core_globalizationwinners = -0.27
eligibility_dummy:core_globalizationwinners = 0.22
```

Both `eligibility_dummy` and `core_globalizationwinners` are dummy variables. Calculating the marginal effect by hand for `eligibility_dummy = 1` and `core_globalizationwinners = 0` yields:

```r
-0.24*1 + (-0.27)*0 + 0.22*0 = -0.24
```

and I get exactly that result from the `margins()` output. Doing it for `core_globalizationwinners = 1`, I expect to get about

```r
-0.24*1 + (-0.27)*1 + 0.22*1 = -0.29.
```

However, the output of the `margins()` function yields an estimate of -0.015.

As far as I understood, and to [quote the author](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html):

> The `at` argument allows you to calculate marginal effects at representative cases (sometimes “MERs”) or marginal effects at means - or any other statistic - (sometimes “MEMs”), which are marginal effects for particularly interesting (sets of) observations in a dataset. This differs from marginal effects on subsets of the original data (see the next section for a demonstration of that) in that it operates on a modified set of the full dataset wherein particular variables have been replaced by specified values. This is helpful because it allows for calculation of marginal effects for counterfactual datasets (e.g., what if all women were instead men? what if all democracies were instead autocracies? what if all foreign cars were instead domestic?).

This seems possible because the "at = " creates counterfactuals. But why does only one coefficient change (the one for `core_globalizationwinner = 1`) and not the other one?

I also tried to subset the data:

```r
margins_sub <- lm(populism_avg_std ~ eligibility_dummy * 
    core_globalizationwinners + male + east_europe, 
    data = tomodel_pid_full_pop) %>%
  margins(data = 
 tomodel_pid_full_pop[to_model_pid_full_pop$core_globalizationwinners 
    == 1, ]) %>%
  summary() %>%
  filter(factor == "eligibility_dummy")
```

but this also gave me the same result as in the "at =" configuration?

Any clarification on why this is the case would be highly appreciated.